# Oracle's MySQL vs. MariaDB vs. Drizzle

Tags: mysql, mariadb, drizzle

I've used MySQL in the past but I have not touched it since around when Oracle bought Sun. Now that Oracle has began pushing out their own MySQL updates on the 5.x branch I've pondered the following:

There is the Oracle branch as well as two popular forks: Maria and Drizzle. I've been trying to find an objective comparison as to why I would consider one of the two forks instead of using the Oracle branch. I've also been trying to figure out what are the main proponents for each fork that make them differ from the Oracle branch.

These are some specifics that I thought of while searching:

- Drizzle's website says that they have re-organized the code to make it more plugin-based - what is the benefit of that?
- Maria's website says that they have made some enhancements but I don't really understand what is so great about them.
- MariaDB is a drop-in replacement - that's pretty awesome as I don't have to make any major changes. But I'm trying to figure out why I would drop Maria in over the regular MySQL though.
- Are any of Oracle's updates relevant to the common developer who just uses common SQL functions? Since this is a relational DB question assume I would use JOIN.

Sites that I have visited:
Drizzle: http://www.drizzle.org/
MariaDB: http://mariadb.org/
MySQL Community Version: http://www.mysql.com/products/community/
Oracle press release on MySQL 5.6: http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1583744
MySQL is gone: http://zerolinesofcode.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/mysql-is-gone-here-comes-mariadb-and-drizzle/

If you were going to build a web app that would probably serve between 1,000-10,000 users a day with 4-5 tables of data - what factors would you consider for each of these?

I understand there are different variables that go into choosing a database; I understand that I have not mentioned hardware; I understand that you might think a NoSQL solution would be better, and I might agree with you. However, I am curious as to how one would approach this from a relational database standpoint.

Has anyone tried each of these out before?

Comment: I think it would help your question if you summarized your findings so far and linked to relevant pages of the sites you mention. For example what enhancements does Maria's site list exactly?

Comment: Is this question beyond  the intellectual capacity of SO cummunity ? If so please keep this question Open. I do not see any reason to close this question.

Comment: this link has some good feature level comparisions: http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/saved_compare/Drizzle-vs-MySQL

Comment: @casperOne Please show some leniency here - this is a very important question, and ranks highly on Google. There are factual answers - Drizzle's plugin system, Maria's Bug fixes etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter to the "owners" of SO that something is useful so long as SO's "rules" are followed. I recently edited an answer to fix a simple syntax error and had it rejected because the edit violated the spirit of the OP's intentions!  lol what really? So your calls for leniency on this question are 3 years old and fell on deaf ears. Sad, because its a great question.